# Powershell Invoke-Webrequest post method - incorrect payload length

Tags: powershell, post

I am trying to submit a form using invoke-webrequst cmdlet, and this is the code

```powershell
$postParams = @{regno='1234567';dob='01/01/1997';B1='Get Marks'} 
$response = Invoke-Webrequest -Uri ("http://studentresulsts/res.asp") -Body $postParams -Method Post -Debug -OutFile out.html
VERBOSE: POST http://studentresulsts/res.asp with -1-byte payload
VERBOSE: received 13-byte response of content type text/html
```

The $response comes back as 'Access Denied' (13-byte response)

The payload length is shown as 1-byte while $postParams is clearly more than that. Wondering if that's the reason I am getting 'Access Denied'.

Checked the form manually in browser and it works fine with correct field values.

I am using powershell 4.0

Answer : Okay, I was missing referrer URL in the header which the server was looking for, then I included referrer and it works fine :) . My new script looks like this. Thanks for your help...

```powershell
$postParams = @{regno='1234567';dob='01/01/1997';B1='Get Marks'} 
$headervals = @{'Referer'='http://studentresulsts/gdslplus/gdslform.htm';'Content-Type'='application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
$response = Invoke-Webrequest -Uri ("http://studentresulsts/res.asp") -Body $postParams -Method Post -Debug -OutFile out.html
```

Comment: Your command looks good, but it doesn't look like you are authenticating anywhere. Do you need username/pass to access _http://studentresulsts/res.asp_?

Comment: this is an anonymous website, no authentication required. Neither am I using proxy server to authenticate to it.

Comment: Maybe the `$postParams` are case sensitive? I take it you sniffed them using fiddler or equivalent and you can see there are no auth cookies being passed around? The fact that you don't have to manually authenticate does not mean the access isn't verified(e.g. trusted sites in IE). Perhaps you are missing a crucial header?

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you don't have to manually authenticate does not mean the access isn't verified(e.g. trusted sites in IE).

Perhaps you are missing a crucial header?